# How to analytically calculate the tilting angle and aperture of an expansion fan?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, aerodynamics

I'm trying to calculate analytically how the expansion fan is positioned relative to the flow. Knowing the incoming Mach number (3.927) and the wedge angle (117°) I'd like to calculate the other two angles (in the figure, 46° and 11.3° are obtained experimentally).

The 11.3° angle should be the expansion fan "aperture angle", and I think is obtained just doing $\mu_\text{final} -\mu_\text{initial}$ using the Prandtl-Meyer equation, but I cannot find a way to calculate the other angle.

Beware that the actual body is not 2D or flat, but it's a cone. Right now, though, I'd be good just calculating that 46° for the case of a 2D wedge.

[image: the problem]

[image: full body]

Comment: Where did you get this picture? Give a link if you can.

Comment: I made it actually, it's from an experiment I'm doing. So I'm sure from the actual images that that angle is 46° but I don't know how to calculate it analytically to see the differences between theory and experiments.

Comment: Is this a flow with cylindrical symmetry? How is the axis of symmetry relative to the horizontal line in this figure?

Comment: it is actually yes. The axis of symmetry would be normal to the hypotenuse of that triangle in the figure. I can draw the complete body if you want.

Comment: Yes, it would be good to see the whole body.

Comment: I updated the question with the picture. The wedge on the previous figure is a detail of the flare at the end of the body

Comment: OK! Thank you. Is the Mach number determined for the oncoming flow or is it local to the tail?

Comment: It's determined by the flow, and should be the mach after the two shocks. But I have to say that seems like too high, and in fact I checked my calculations and the actual Mach number after the second shock and before the expansion should be M = 2.2768. So the first picture is wrong, sorry.

Comment: Then it would be better to report the Mach number before the first shock. Are there dimensions in millimeters? What  is the ratio of specific heats at constant pressure and at constant volume?

Comment: The Mach number after the first shock is 3.927, k = 1.4, R = 287